# Possible to make a program to check Windows hosts file every minute?

Tags: windows, web, hosts-file

I know how to block facebook using hosts file.

Problem is that I can just easily edit hosts file and do facebook again.

So if there is a program that reports whether hosts file currently contains the line

```
127.0.0.1       www.facebook.com
```

and if not, it will report it to some email report@XXX.com

I also make sure I can't quit the program just to go to facebook. That is, the program is password protected when I try to quit it or edit it.

Of course I am not asking anyone here to code it for me. I am just curious if this is even possible to make.

Comment: The short answer is Yes. You might have to be a little creative with the security aspect. For instance the user might not be able to have administrator access locally to make it so they can't stop it.

Comment: Why make a program to "check the hosts file" when you could just _make a program to block Facebook_ (or any other site)

Comment: @Insane  Because I will be tempted to just change the settings of that program to do facebook. So I need some facebook-blocking program that, if I change its setting, someone else will get notified of my doing that.

Comment: Whoever has enough rights to edit the hosts file, probably also has enough rights to kill the process in Task Manager for that watch program, regardless of any password protection built into the program itself. Whatever you try to achieve, it's not clear from your description of it thus far.

Comment: @dxiv I have a human monitor. It may be my parents or friends or even any other 3rd person. They will receive the reports from the program like "The user is blocking facebook at 11:15pm, 20151215" I will pay small fine to the monitor. Will this be possible?

Comment: What are you mean by "make a program"? You can look for ready tools https://www.raymond.cc/blog/3-portable-tools-monitor-files-folders-changes/ and if you want to write such tool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350717/how-can-i-detect-changes-to-files-from-windows but the question is - **why you just don't create a non-administrative user(s) account(s)?!?**